# AWK: join separate words from 2 consecutive lines

Tags: bash, awk, text-parsing

I'd like an AWK command that joins separate words:

> **1st part is in the end of the line, end up with "_".**
>
> **2nd part is in the beginning of the next line.**

(PS: there are some lines that have both the 2nd and 1st part like in the example below)

Example:

```
Bla bla bla bla SATU_
RDAY bla bla, bla bla
bla bla bla bla bla SUN_
DAY: bla bla bla bla M_
ONDAY. Bla bla bla bla TU_
ESDAY, bla bla bla.
```

Result:

```
Line 1: SATURDAY
Line 3: SUNDAY
Line 4: MONDAY
Line 5: TUESDAY
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ awk 'p~/_$/{sub(/_$/,"",p);print "Line " (NR-1) ":", p $1}{p=$NF}' file
Line 1: SATURDAY
Line 3: SUNDAY:
Line 4: MONDAY.
Line 5: TUESDAY,
```

Comment: It's customary to comment when downvoting.

Comment: The downvote ages! Me and even Ed was downovoted also!

Comment: ++ for an elegant solution, but the removal of the trailing punctuation is missing.
As an aside: all down-votes happened at the same time, suggesting a single down-voter.

Answer (score 1):

With GNU awk for multi-char RS:

```
$ awk -v RS='[[:alpha:]]+_\n[[:alpha:]]+' 'RT!=""{sub(/_\n/,"",RT); print RT}' file
SATURDAY
SUNDAY
MONDAY
TUESDAY
```

or with any awk:

```
$ awk 'w{w=w $1; gsub(/[^[:alpha:]]/,"",w); print w; w=""} /_$/{w=$NF}' file
SATURDAY
SUNDAY
MONDAY
TUESDAY
```

and if you really want the starting line numbers included then with any awk:

```
$ awk 'w{w=w $1; gsub(/[^[:alpha:]]/,"",w); printf "Line %d: %s\n", NR-1, w; w=""} /_$/{w=$NF}' file
Line 1: SATURDAY
Line 3: SUNDAY
Line 4: MONDAY
Line 5: TUESDAY
```

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure of all your requirements, but:

```
awk 'x  {sub("[^A-Z].*", "", $1); print "Line "n": "x $1; x = ""}
     sub("_$", "", $NF) {x = x $NF; n = NF}' input.txt
```

hth

Answer (score 0):

With GNU awk:

```
$ awk 'p{print gensub(/[^A-Z]$/,"","g",$1);p=0}/_$/{printf "%s",gensub("_","","g",$NF);p=1}' file
SATURDAY
SUNDAY
MONDAY
TUESDAY
```

Comment: @EdMorton Ok, Ed - Noted.

Comment: Downvoting without comment is my favorite situation.

Comment: Lol, so all but one got downvoted. :D (just to be clear: the only one not downvoted wasn't around when it happened)

Comment: @JamesBrown By the way all answers right now in here have a downvote....

Answer (score 0):

A POSIX-compliant solution:

```
awk '
  firstPart != "" { sub(/[[:punct:]]$/, "", $1); print firstPart $1 } 
  $NF ~ /._$/ { firstPart=substr($NF, 1, length($NF) - 1); next } 
  { firstPart= "" }
' file
```

- *Pattern* (condition) `firstPart != ""` is true only if a token of interest was found on the *previous* line and only then executes the associated *action* (`{ ... }`):

  - `sub(/[[:punct:]]$/, "", $1)` replaces (`sub()`) a trailing (`$`) instance of a punctuation character (`[[:punct:]]`), if any, in the 1st field (`$1`) with the empty string, thereby effectively removing it.
  - `print firstPart $1` prints the direct concatenation of the token of interest from the previous line with the (modified) 1st field, simply by placing `firstPart` and `$1` next to each other, separated only by a space.
- Pattern `$NF ~ /._$/` tests if the last field (`$NF`) ends in (`$`) `_` (preceded by at least 1 other character (`.`)).

  - `firstPart=substr($NF, 1, length($NF) - 1)` stores the contents of the last field except for the trailing `_` in variable `firstPart`.
  - `next` skips processing of the remainder of the script for the line at hand and moves to the next line.
- Action `{ firstPart= "" }`, because it is not preceded by a pattern, is processed unconditionally - *if reached*:

  - Here it is only reached if the line at hand contains no token of interest.
  - Resetting `firstPart` signals to the next script cycle that nothing is to be printed for the next line.